# Kalman filter. Why does it use the control u(k) of the current time step and not the previous?

Tags: kalman-filter

So, the assumption of

$\hat{x}_k = F \hat{x}_{k-1} + B u_k + w_k$

(Taken from wikipedia)

How come the assumption is made on the previous estimated value of $\hat{x}$ transitioning to the current time step, but it uses control $u$ of the current time step and not the previous?

What if, then, the estimated state $\hat{x}$ is used on a control loop with $u_k=-K\hat{x}_k$. But $\hat{x}_k$ depends on $u_k$ which then creates an algebraic loop, doesn't it?

Or, if said model is already correct, which would require $u_k$ to be known in advance, how would I implement the filter if $u_k$ is not known until time $k$?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: $u$ is not a "command", you should correct your terminology!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry, I was typing with control system in mind and $u$ is the system's command to me. Should probably be just 'input' for statistics.

Comment: Don't trust Wikipedia. It can contains mistakes!

Comment: I guess you mean the systems **control**, not command.  In statistics that would be disturbance term or noise term (or input). Can you edit also your title?

Comment: I think you might want to reread the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamic_system_model) and focus on its explanation of what these terms *mean*.  Ignore the subscripts--that's merely a matter of convention.